# Caroma smart toilet isn't filling

Tags: toilet

My Caroma Smart dual flush toilet isn’t filling up. Water supply is turned on,but there is no water coming into the thank. The tank is completely empty. I manually filled the tank  up with water and iit flushed appropriately,but didn’t fill back up on its own.  I can’t even hear the water running. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. With the typos, it's a little hard to understand what you mean; editing the question to clarify would help (click the "edit" link under your question).

Comment: Thank you,I just read my question and I meant to write that my toilet flushed appropriately when I manually put water in the tank with a bucket. The tank is completely empty,there isn’t any water coming into the tank.

Comment: When did this behavior start? What changed? How do you know the water supply is turned on? How's the rest of the water in the house?

Comment: Started yesterday,it was flushed earlier in the day,and when had to flushed later,it wouldn’t flush.  I took the lid off and there wasn’t any water in the tank. I checked the cut off on the wall and it was on. The water is good in the rest of the house,I have an identical toilet in the hall bathroom and it’s flushing fine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there's a problem with the inlet valve, which should fill the tank when it falls below the set depth. Here's a video on maintenance for a Caroma Dual Flush:

http://www.caromausa.com/resources/videos/articles/29.php

And here's a PDF on servicing the inlet valve:

http://www.caromausa.com/database/rte/files/QuietFlow%202%20Service%20Guide.pdf

Comment: @NellieC Let us know what the problem was and how you fixed it.